# Store form data as single cookie

Tags: javascript

I have a cookie set on my site which tells me what type of device people are using.

the values are as follows

- S
- M
- T
- D

the value of the cookie can be either MS, TS or DS.

I want to create a form where the user can update there cookie manually and when they submit the form it will update the cookie but i also want the form to already have the current cookie values selected.

i tried this code but i get a undefined cookie value.

Heres the form

```
<form name="devicePrefs">
    <input type="radio" name="deviceType" value="D">Desktop<br>
    <input type="radio" name="deviceType" value="T">Tablet<br>
    <input type="radio" name="deviceType" value="M">Mobile<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="skipSeat" value="S">Skip Seating Plan<br>
    <input type="button" value="Set to Cookie" onClick="storeValues()">
</form>
```

here is the javascript i used

```
 var today = new Date();
 var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days 
 function setCookie(name, value) { 
    document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString(); 
 }

  function storeValues() { 
    setCookie("ATGDevicePrefs", devicePrefs.deviceType.value, devicePrefs.deviceType.skipSeat); 
  }
```

thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two paramters function and pass 3 arguments to it

you should use

```
  function storeValues() { 
    setCookie("ATGDevicePrefs", devicePrefs.deviceType.value +
              devicePrefs.deviceType.skipSeat); 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for that i know get the value for the skip seat field but still get an undefined value for the deviceType radiobox any ideas?

Comment: It could have worked even the parameters mismatch.Except the result would be not the expected one

Comment: Is the site being accessed is secure?

Comment: @user2170420 If you use jQuery you can get the value of selected radio button using `$('input[name=deviceType]:checked').val()`

Comment: You should give attribute checked to one of the radio buttons in the group

Comment: I used   function storeValues() { 
setCookie("ATGDevicePrefs", $('input[name=deviceType]:checked').val() + $('input[name=skipSeat]:checked').val()); 
}
which now works but if i dont select a device type or a skipSeat i get a undefined value is there a way around this